# Can you track how much time you spend on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

Many a time it happens that I login to Facebook to see some status or to see how many of my friends are online at that time. It seems as if it would take only 5-10 minutes, but then I start to search for some other friends or do any other work on Facebook. It is not just my story but it is common to teenagers like me. Afterwards we regret that we have wasted this much time, but by then it is too late.

**Is there a way I can track the exact time I am spending on Facebook** so that I can manage my time more meaningfully?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few applications out there to track the time you spend on sites, two that do what you are after:

- [RescueTime](https://www.rescuetime.com/) - Will track everything you do, so you can get an idea of what you spend your time on (including Facebook). The tracking is free, but you can pay for premium which lets you block sites. It will work on your phone as well as the computer.
- [TimeRabbit](http://www.gigawatch.com/TimeRabbit/) - An app that will sit in the background and just monitors how much time you spend on Facebook